# Take a single parameter "dimensions" and make it into 2 values "width" and "height"

Tags: python-3.x

I have been given an assignment to create an image of a flag. So far I have completely figured out the part about coloring the flag correctly, but I can't figure out what to do with the dimension parameter.

I must use a single parameter "d" for dimensions of the flag. then somehow reference that parameter to create a variable for the width and the height. I'm not sure how to approach this part.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def tri_vertical( d, c1, c2, c3 ) :
    ''' Return a new flag of dimension d and equally-spaced colors
        c1, c2, and c3'''
     # create image of appropriate size
    d = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    BACKGROUND_COLOR = "black"

    im =  Image.new( 'RGB', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), BACKGROUND_COLOR )

    # get a drawable canvas of image im
    canvas = ImageDraw.Draw( im )

    x = 0
    y = 0
    wi = (1/3)*WIDTH
    h = HEIGHT
    xy = [ (x, y), (x + wi, y + h) ]
    canvas.rectangle( xy, fill=c1 )

    x = (1/3)*WIDTH
    y = 0
    wi = (1/3)*WIDTH
    h = HEIGHT
    xy = [ (x, y), (x + wi, y + h) ]
    canvas.rectangle( xy, fill=c2 )

    x = (2/3)*WIDTH
    y = 0
    wi = (1/3)*WIDTH
    h = h
    xy = [ (x, y), (x + wi, y + h) ]
    canvas.rectangle( xy, fill=c3)

    return im
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where is your problem? Are you just looking for `w, h = d`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. Just replace

```
d = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

with

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = d
```

and you'll be good to go.